# iPad Keyboard Error in swift 3

Tags: ipad, swift3, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

After I type on User Name and Password text boxes in app and then click on "Login" button, I got following error and app is crashed.

> ***** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3599.6/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:432
>   2017-05-09 10:30:00.984744 NetCast[657:113345] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
>   *** First throw call stack:**

I encounter that problem whenever I `login`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished error Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947608/waituntilalltasksarefinished-error-swift)

Comment: @JigarTarsariya,  thanks bro. I can solve it now.